# str_replace not replacing spaces with commas for data accessed via curl. PHP

Tags: php, curl

```
    $csv = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $csv = str_replace(" ", ",", $csv);

    echo $csv;
```

`475064,700,1170134 464073,53,145098 334552,52,123754 480652,58,238502 569677,52,135520 883946,13,2012 445735,43,50649 743921,35,23380 736097,23,6902 779420,36,24887 -1,1,0 693512,26,9632 396218,35,22960 469085,37,29814 744808,15,2518 644784,27,10122 466101,10,1250 136344,59,259114 361312,32,16880 332231,42,48228 353406,9,1000 216824,32,16912 355831,9,1000 -1,1,0 151118,14 -1,-1 -1,-1`

For some reason the str_replace command isn't working on this `$csv` string.

Comment: perhaps those are the line breaks at the end of a line? or tabs or ...

Comment: `string(387) "475068,700,1170134 464075,53,145098 334553,52,123754 480656,...`

Comment: Ah, yeah thanks @Dagon spot on.

Comment: \s and preg_replace would be my approach

Comment: I think this symbols "\n" or "\r", you can try `echo n2br($csv)` and show output. If you get `<br />` then you get "\n" symbols. And need replace him by `str_replace("\n",",",$csv)` but why?